# Additional Discount Field Is Non-Editable When Products are segmented

Tags: cpq, quote, quotelineitem, cpq-plugins, qcp

On Quote Line Editor, we have a custom field named "**Additional Discount**".(Data Type Percentage).
We have added product and created two segments and we land up into an issue, where for Segment 1 we are able to edit Additional Discount field but for Segment 2 its appearing as read-only.
We explicitly tried to make that field editable using QCP script but it did not work .
Please suggest and advice.

```
if (line.SBQQ__Discount__c && fieldName === 'SBQQ__Discount__c') {
        return true
}
```

[image]